# DataView Filter not finding match

Tags: c#, filter, dataview

I'm selecting a DataView row based on a Tag value from a treeview. It Works fine most of the time, but under certain conditions does not return a record. I wrote the code below to test each row before I call the filter.

```
        private void TreeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
        if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null)
        {
            TreeNode tn = treeView1.SelectedNode;
            Console.WriteLine(tn.Tag.ToString());
            selectedTag = tn.Tag.ToString();

            dv.Table = ds.Tables["ProductStruct"];
            foreach (DataRow dr in dv.Table.Rows)
            {
                bool test = dr["uniqueID"].ToString() == tn.Tag.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(dr["uniqueID"].ToString() + " and " + tn.Tag.ToString() + test);
            }
            dv.RowFilter = "uniqueID = '" + tn.Tag.ToString() + "'";
            Console.WriteLine(dv.RowFilter.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(dv.Count.ToString());
        }
    }
```

the output is as follows:

```
12331233-200-00e
12331233 and 12331233-200-00eFalse
12331233-100-000 and 12331233-200-00eFalse
12331233-200-00e and 12331233-200-00eTrue
12331233-300-000 and 12331233-200-00eFalse
12331233-400-000 and 12331233-200-00eFalse
12331233-500-000 and 12331233-200-00eFalse
12331233-600-000 and 12331233-200-00eFalse
12331233-700-000 and 12331233-200-00eFalse
12331233-800-000 and 12331233-200-00eFalse
12331233-900-000 and 12331233-200-00eFalse
uniqueID = '12331233-200-00e'
0
```

As you can see the bool test is true for one record but filter fails to return it. Any help is appreciated, I hate to use a loop where a single line should do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

The loop you run overrides the value of the bool and loops as many times as the count of row exists in your table.

Inside the loop, use return to escape once you find the match. It will not go through all the rows. This will return only 1 value.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dv.Table.Rows)
        {
            bool test = dr["uniqueID"].ToString() == tn.Tag.ToString();               

           if(dr["uniqueID"].ToString() == tn.Tag.ToString()){
              Console.WriteLine(dr["uniqueID"].ToString() + " and " + tn.Tag.ToString() + test);
               dv.RowFilter = "uniqueID = '" + tn.Tag.ToString() + "'";
               return;
           }
        }
```

If you are expecting more matches, move the

```
dv.RowFilter = "uniqueID = '" + tn.Tag.ToString() + "'";
```

Inside the loop and encapsulate it with if statement.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dv.Table.Rows)
            {
                bool test = dr["uniqueID"].ToString() == tn.Tag.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(dr["uniqueID"].ToString() + " and " + tn.Tag.ToString() + test);

               if(dr["uniqueID"].ToString() == tn.Tag.ToString()){
                dv.RowFilter = "uniqueID = '" + tn.Tag.ToString() + "'";
               }
            }
```

This will run the filter each time it finds a match.

I hope this helps.

Comment: i want the filter to select that single record, which it is not. the bool "test" is only so i could prove to myself that there was a record for filter to get...

Comment: just need to add return to exit the loop once you found what you need.